# AJAX call freezes browser for a bit while it gets response and executes success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an AJAX call to my webserver which fetches a lot of data.  i show a loading image that spins while the ajax call is executed and then fades away.

the thing i have noticed is that all of the browsers on this particular call will make it non-responsive for about 7 seconds.  That being said, the loading image is NOT spinning as what i had planned while the fetch was occurring.

I did not know if this was something that happens or if there is a way around to, in a sense cause there to be a fork() so that it does 1 thing, while my loading icon still spins.

THoughts?  Ideas?

below is the code as someone wanted to see it:

```
$("div.loadingImage").fadeIn(500);//.show();
            setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: WEBSERVICE_URL + "/getChildrenFromTelTree",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "pText": parentText,
                    "pValue": parentValue,
                    "pr_id": LOGGED_IN_PR_ID,
                    "query_input": $("#queryInput").val()
                }),
                success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //alert("winning");
                    //var childNodes = eval(result["getChildrenFromTelTreeResult"]);
                    if (result.getChildrenFromTelTreeResult == "") {
                        alert("No Children");
                    } else {
                        var childNodes = JSON.parse(result.getChildrenFromTelTreeResult);
                        var newChild;
                        //alert('pText: '+parentText+"\npValue: "+parentValue+"\nPorofileID: "+ LOGGED_IN_PR_ID+"\n\nFilter Input; "+$("#queryInput").val() );
                        //alert(childNodes.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
                            TV.trackChanges();
                            newChild = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode();
                            newChild.set_text(childNodes[i].pText);
                            newChild.set_value(childNodes[i].pValue);
                            //confirmed that newChild is set to ServerSide through debug and get_expandMode();
                            parentNode.get_nodes().add(newChild);
                            TV.commitChanges();
                            var parts = childNodes[i].pValue.split(",");
                            if (parts[0] != "{fe_id}" && parts[0] != "{un_fe_id}") {
                                newChild.set_expandMode(Telerik.Web.UI.TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSide);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //TV.expand();
                    //recurseStart(TV);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, message) {
                    alert("errrrrror");
                }
            }).always(function () {
                    $("div.loadingImage").fadeOut();
                });
                },500);
```

A corworker of mine noticed this issue, and suggested i add a setTimeout(function(){..},500); but it does not fix the issue at hand, so it will most likely be removed.

Comment: What's the `Content-Length` of the response?

Comment: You aren't using `async: false` right?

Comment: is your web-server at localhost? either its synchronous call or the back-end script is doing something insane

Comment: i thought by default async was true... which is correct, so there was no setting to false.

Comment: how would i find the content-length?  is that an attribute?

Comment: You should show the code for your ajax call. It's like asking for help fixing a problem with your car, but you didn't open the hood so we can see inside.

Comment: The response-text:  i pasted into a site to count characters.  68913 characters long.

Comment: @MrOBrian the code is currently not needed.  Under the current contraints, this call will set up about 20 characters, then return 68,913 characters, parse it with  JSON.parse(..)  and finally iterate through the constructed array once.  Either the lag is in the retrieval of the data, or going through an array once (like 1300 objects or so if i am correct).  --but... for you, i added the code.  ;)

Comment: I bet it's the creation of the objects in that `for` loop.  Try commenting out everything inside it (but leave the loop itself) and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: More than likely it is the DOM manipulations that are causing the issues. When ever you query the dom to either find a parent, a property, or to add more elements the dom has to go through a refresh. This refresh will slow down your page and cause "hang".

Comment: @MrOBrian I commented out the forloop contents and it was done running in about half a second.  It seems that executing that loop is causing the hangup

Comment: Now that we have figured out where this hangup is coming from, what sort of thing can we do to allow it to stop the hangup?  My samples were saying to have the track and commit in the loop incase there is an interruption.

Comment: well, it's all the object creation and DOM manipulation within the loop that's causing the hang, the loop itself should run quite fast. You may need to come up with some other way of adding all those objects to the page. One thing that might slightly speed it up is to make the element they are being added to invisible before the loop and then visible again after, that way it doesn't get redrawn each iteration

Comment: I had moved the get_nodes() outside of the loop so that it picks up speed with that respect.  I need the newChild = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode(); in there, otherwise it will only add the last object in the loop from what i just tested.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since JavaScript is single threaded, a lot of sync processing will hang up the event queue and prevent other code from executing. In your case, it's the for-loop thats locking up the browser while it's executing. 
What you can try is putting all your iterations into your event queue.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < childNodes.length ; i = i + 1) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function(i) {
            // code-here
        }, 0)
    })(i)
}
```

This should space out the processing and not force the browser to finish them all at once. The self executing function is there to create a closure to hold on to the value of the loop counter i.

Comment: shouldn't it be       "setTimeout(function(i) {
            // code-here
        }, 0, i)"