# large promise and user actions, not allowing click events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, promise

I am very new to promises.  I have an angular app that, at one point, has a very large promise a lots of `.then` statements.

The view where the promise lives has and close button, taking the user home.

When the promise is being executed and the user clicks the close, nothing happens.  Once the promise has completed I can successfully click close.

I am assuming it has something to do with the promise executing but really don't know why or how to troubleshoot this. Any help/insight is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you share your code if you want help

Comment: I would bet that the close button is being disabled by code just before the requests start, and enabled when the last one finishes. But cannot be sure without your code.

Comment: What I recommend you to do, is to use a Spinner/Loader when you have some asynch functions that take a while to complete. I recommend you the following library:

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

Comment: Sounds like there's some blocking code in there. For example, synchronous AJAX. Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11976830/3478010).