# setTimeout doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my application I am loading user posts using the ajax scroll down feature.

The for loop iteration takes too much time, browser freezes until the results are displayed. So I implemented a setTimeout method to fix that, but for some reason the flow doesn't go inside the setTimeout method on debugging.

Also the page is blank, data is not rendered.

```
  success : function(responseJson) {
        $("#loadingdata").toggle();
        enableScrolling();

        if($.isEmptyObject(responseJson)){
          $("#noMorePosts").toggle();
          disableScrolling();
          paginationComplete=true;
        }

        $.each(responseJson, function (index) {     
          (function(index) {
            setTimeout(function(index) { //the flow doesn't move inside this
              var resp_JSON=responseJson[index];
              var dateObj=resp_JSON.postCreationTime;
              resp_JSON.postCreationTime = moment(dateObj).format("h:mm a, ddd, MMM Do YY");
              var timeago = moment(dateObj).fromNow();
              resp_JSON.timeago = timeago; 
              resp_JSON.username=userName;               
              var post_template = $('#homepostcontainertemplate').html();
              Mustache.parse(post_template);   
              var post_info = Mustache.to_html(post_template, resp_JSON);
              $('#homepublisherpostsdiv').append(post_info);
              $('div').linkify();
            });
          })(index);
        });
```

When the flow reaches setTimeout the next code it hits is the jquery lib

[image]

Am I doing it right or missing something?

**Note:** I get the responseJson data from the server fine. Without the setTimeout the data is loaded on the page.

Comment: `console.log(1);` before the first line on the `setTimeout` callback, does it print in the console ?

Comment: I put it just before setTimeout, after (function(index) {; It does print 1 ten times in the console; but it also says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postCreationTime' of undefined 10 times. Probably the code within setTimeout is unable to read the responseJSON

Comment: Is there a particular reason of the usage of encapsulated function inside the $.each? How is it different from writing straight $.each(responseJson, function (index) { setTimeout(function() { ...

Comment: I got the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974237/ajax-call-freezes-browser-for-a-bit-while-it-gets-response-and-executes-success
Besides the problem is on every iteration the resp_JSON variable is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setTimeout takes an argument-less function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), so having `index` as an argument is a little odd. I suspect that index is undefined so `responseJson[index]` is throwing out of bound exception (as evidenced by `console.log(1)` showing up as per Niloct's comment). If you change your code to:

```
    $.each(responseJson, function (index) {     
        setTimeout(function() { // no index in the argument list
          var resp_JSON=responseJson[index];
          var dateObj=resp_JSON.postCreationTime;
          resp_JSON.postCreationTime = moment(dateObj).format("h:mm a, ddd, MMM Do YY");
          var timeago = moment(dateObj).fromNow();
          resp_JSON.timeago = timeago; 
          resp_JSON.username=userName;               
          var post_template = $('#homepostcontainertemplate').html();
          Mustache.parse(post_template);   
          var post_info = Mustache.to_html(post_template, resp_JSON);
          $('#homepublisherpostsdiv').append(post_info);
          $('div').linkify();
        });
    });
```

I suspect it will work.

(edited to take into account jjaulimsing's comment about not needing the encapsulating function.)

Comment: Hi Syaz, can you please accept the username edit request please. I am trying to remove references from search engine. Thanks in advance.